# Exclude related fields in model._meta.get_fields()

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model currently defined like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField()
    name = models.CharField()
    desc = models.CharField()
```

Another model `Subcategory` has a `ForeignKey` defined on `Category`.

When I run:

```
Category._meta.get_fields()
```

I get:

```
(<ManyToOneRel: siteapp.subcategory>, <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: ID>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: name>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: desc>)
```

However, I don't want the `ManyToOneRel` fields; I just want the others.

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ManyToOneRel
field_list = []
for field in modelClass._meta.get_fields():
    if not isinstance(field, ManyToOneRel):
        field_list.append(field)
```

However, is there a better way to do this, with or without using the model `_meta` API?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? Where are you using this code and why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I need to get a list of attributes like `max_length`, etc. for each model field.

Comment: Yes but why? If you're creating a form, why not use a ModelForm which does all this for you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's not for a form, it's for an internal page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `concrete_fields` property.

```
Category._meta.concrete_fields
```

However this is an internal Django API, and it may be better to use `get_fields()` with your own filtering, even though it may be a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue creating a serializer mixin that treated only `GenericRelaTion` fields. Unfortunately, when you use the `get_fields()` the `ManyToOneRel` in somecases appear principally when you need to get `attname` of a field. Therefore I created a function that treates this issue skiping all the `ManyToOneRel` from fields:

```
def get_generic_relation_fields(self):
    """
    This function returns all the GenericRelation 
    fields needed to return the values that are 
    related such as polymorphic models.
    """
    other_field = [field for field in self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields()]
    fields = [field.attname for field in self.Meta.model._meta.get_fields() if not isinstance(field, (ManyToOneRel))]
    generic_relation_fields = []
    for field in fields:
        get_type = self.Meta.model._meta.get_field(field)
        field_type = get_type.__class__.__name__
    
        if field_type == "GenericRelation": #<----- change field name to filter different fields.
                generic_relation_fields.append(field)

    return generic_relation_fields
```

Usage:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    . . .
    first_name = GenericRelation(MyUserPolymorphic)
    last_name = GenericRelation(MyUserPolymorphic)
    whatever = GenericRelation(MyUserPolymorphic)


class MyModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        fields = [field for field in get_generic_relation_fields(self)]
        print("FIELDS ---->", fields)
        . . .
```

output on POST:

```
FIELDS ----> ['first_name', 'last_name', 'whatever']
```

However, there I added 'GenericRelation' field you can add other fields to be filtered and treated as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution for this, and I've ended up writing my own script which while not the most clean pythonic code, works. I thought to put it here if someone stumbles upon it in the future.

```
[field for field in fields if str(type(field)) !=  "<class 'django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey'>"]
```

I have also used this script as follows to get a dict in the format of {field_name:field_value}

```
{
   field.name: (
     getattr(self, field.name)
     if str(type(field))
     != "<class 'django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey'>"
     else getattr(self, field.name).id
     )
   for field in fields
   if str(type(field)) 
    != "<class 'django.db.models.fields.reverse_related.ManyToOneRel'>"}
```

I had to do an additional check for ForeignKey constraints as usually showing the field value didn't make sense in that case